# using '*' as argument for reverse polish expression doesn't work

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to create a program which evaluates a reverse polish expression. Everything work's well till i try to make a multiplication.For example it works for this arguments: `Program_name 2 3 + or 2 3 - 4 /` but if try `3 4 *` is doesn't work anymore.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>



char getcharacter(const char *c){
    return c[0];  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[10],i=0;
    char c;
    if(argc>3)
    {
       while(--argc>0){
           c=getcharacter(*++argv);
           printf("%c ",c);// for debug
           if(c>47&&c<58)
           {
                a[i]=c-'0';
                i++;
           }
           else if(c=='-')
           {
                a[i-2]=a[i-2]-a[i-1];
                a[i-1]=0;
                i--;
           }
           else if(c=='+')
           {
                a[i-2]=a[i-2]+a[i-1];
                a[i-1]=0;
                i--;
           }
           else if(c=='*')
           {
                a[i-2]=a[i-2]*a[i-1];
                a[i-1]=0;
                i--;
           }
           else if(c=='/')
           {
               if(a[i-2]==0)
                   printf("Error\n");
               else
               {
                   a[i-2]=a[i-2]/a[i-1];
                   a[i-1]=0;
                   i--;
               }
           }
           else printf("U have entered something wrong.");
       }
   }

   else
   {
       printf("Too few arguments");
   }

   printf("Rezultat=%d\n",a[0]);
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: `c>47&&c<58` etc: Don't use _magic  numbers_! And use `ctypes.h`

Comment: It's because the shell replaces '*' with filenames. Your `printf("%c ",c);` should show that clearly.

Comment: Put the `*` in `"` in the argument line. You are subject to wildcard substitution.

Comment: BTW: you are allowed to write `if (c > 47 && c < 58)` instead of `if(c>47&&c<58)`. Spaces are your friends

Comment: BTW your program "work" with one digit number only...

Comment: Next step: make your program work with numbers > 10. And learn what functions are before trying.

Comment: BTW: what's the point of the `getcharacter` function ??

Comment: i made it just for me to use pointers. Thanks a lot for the answers u made my day.

Comment: If you improved your error reporting by changing `printf("U have entered something wrong.");` to, say, `fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected character '%c' in input:\"%s\"\n", c, *argv);` you would be able to diagnose this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid shell wildcards, the parameter needs to be quoted. E.g. use '*' instead of *